# req.body returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

i have installed body parser through npm, required it, set it with express buti am still getting req.body undefined. If someone knows whats wrong please let me know i feel like its something stupid im missing.
This is my app.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const index = require('./routes/index');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

//Create the express server
const app = express();

// Use index routes file
app.use('', index);

// Use the /public folder for our assets
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

// Use body-parser and cookie-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser);

// Set ejs as our templating engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// Error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.status(res.statusCode || 500);
  res.render('error', {error: err.message});
  console.log(err.message);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log('Application running on localhost:3000');

});
```

This is my route index.js file that's making the post

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const movie_controller = require('../controllers/movieController');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');

router.get('/about', (req, res, error) => {
    res.render('about');
});

router.get('/', movie_controller.get_index);
router.get('/currently_playing', movie_controller.get_currently_playing);
router.get('/top_rated', movie_controller.get_top_rated);
router.get('/upcoming', movie_controller.get_upcoming);
router.get('/movie_view/:id', movie_controller.get_movie);
// Post request for a search query
router.post('/search', (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('Query', req.body);

    // Make request for query
    request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=&language=en-
US&query=' + req.body + '&page=1&include_adult=false', (error, response, 
body) => {

        //handle errors
        if(error){res.render('error', {error: error.message})}

        //handle body
        if(response.statusCode === 200){

            //place body data in a variable for later reference
             let movieData = JSON.parse(body);
             let movies = [];

            movieData.results.forEach(movie => {
                 movies.push(movie);
            });

            // Make request for genres
            request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?
api_key=&language=en-US', (error, response, body) => {

                //handle errors
                if(error){res.render('error', {error: error.message})}

                //handle body
                if(response.statusCode === 200){

                    //place body in a variable for later reference
                    let genreData = JSON.parse(body);
                    let genres = [];

                    genreData.genres.forEach(genre => {
                        genres.push(genre);
                    });


                    res.render('results', {movie: movies, genres: genres });

                }


            })
        }

    })

});




module.exports = router;
```

This is where the form is on a header.ejs partial

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search" method="post">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" name="searchQuery" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use the `bodyParser()` before `app.use('', index)` of your router, to avoid any problem just place `app.use('', index)` it in the last.

```
// Use body-parser and cookie-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser);

// Use index routes file
app.use('', index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Express middleware runs in the order you register them (routes included). You have registered the `bodyParser` and `cookieParser` middlewares *after* attaching your routes. Therefore, you will not have the parsed body or cookies by the time your route is encountered.

To fix this, make sure that any middlewares you want to run before your actual route are registered before:

```
const express = require('express')
const index = require('./routes/index');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

//Create the express server
const app = express();

// Use the /public folder for our assets
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

// Use body-parser and cookie-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser);

// Use index routes file
app.use('', index);

...
```

Comment: Wow i'm a moron, all last night I was trying to figure out why this wasn't working. Knew it was something simple, thanks!!

Comment: We’ve all been there haha

Comment: Anyways, Express has [an article](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) on the topic which is well worth the read.

Comment: Cool ill check it out